# Changing robot meta tags with JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meta

I have a strange problem. I have pages with sports events, the events have dates of when they are played (h1). What I'm trying to accomplish is: when the event has ended, the page will change to noindex.

Here is my code currently:

```
if (h1 < +moment().add(172800000)) {

    $('meta[name=robots]').attr('content', "noindex,follow,noodp,noydir");
    $('meta[name=googlebot]').attr('content', "noindex,follow");

    console.log("ARCHIVED");
} else {
    console.log("NOT ARCHIVED");
}
```

The h1 < moments simply compares the start date to the current date + 48 hours. The console.log stuff is working fine which means the if statement works. I've seen MANY posts similar to this, and it would seem that the `$('meta[name=googlebot]').attr('content', "deindex,follow")` *should* work, but it's not.

Do any of you see an error in the code? Am I missing something?

Here are my current meta tags that I'm trying to change

```
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow,noodp,noydir" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow" />
```

Comment: use quotes around values `$('meta[name="robots"]').`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thanks for the reply! However this didn't work either. I had already tried it (and tried it again just now) with no effect. I will edit my post to add the current meta tags, perhaps the problem is there.

Comment: Hi can you please tell me why you would choose to use js/jquery to change the meta instead of server side? You can try this: `$('meta[name="robots"]').attr('content', 'noindex,follow,noodp,noydir');
    $('meta[name="googlebot"]').attr('content', 'noindex,follow');` However the real source code will not change but only the source code in DOM. You can see it change example in Google Chrome DevTools.

Comment: Hi @nstungcom, there is no real reason why I chose to change this with js/jquery, simply that I assumed it would be better. The most important factor in this code is the date comparator (the if). That h1 variable comes from js, and the +moment uses a js library (moment.js). Seeing as how this was all in js, I figured it would be easier to stick with it. However if you know of a better way, or more efficient way, I would love to give it a shot!

Comment: @nstungcom I should add that I'm no expert when it comes to code. I'm checking the pages source code to see if the meta tag changed, perhaps this is my error.... The important thing here is that the bots read the page as noindex.

Comment: Why aren't you doing this server side? Although some bots *may* run the page JS most will probably only see the raw, original, HTML.

Comment: @IanLewis how would I go about doing this server side? php? I need a little nudge in the right direction. Also I know that googlebot will read the JS, but you brought up a good point, I'm not sure if others will.

Comment: Do you use any CMS or did you code it all from scratch? You could use PHP to change the meta the same as you would do with js/jquery. This way you are on the safe side when it come to bots will crawls the updated metas. You may want to provided us more information like where your content is coming from (HTML only or PHP & HTML).

Comment: @nstungcom Thanks for the reply! I'll leave a little more info here to help. My site is based on WP, however the "theme" I use is entirely custom. The majority of the site is PHP generated, as well as some JS. The meta robot tags are hard coded in HTML in the header.php file. I'll leave here an example page of a match thats coming up, and one thats expired. The expired one SHOULD read noindex in the metas. (please note that it's in spanish, sorry if this causes any inconvenience)

Comment: Here are the links

Upcoming match (should be indexed): http://www.apostaralfutbol.com/partido/apostar-manchester-city-vs-barcelona-01-11-16/

Expired match (should be noindex): http://www.apostaralfutbol.com/partido/apostar-valencia-vs-barcelona-22-10-16/

Comment: You can use this Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-post-expiration/ to set the expiration date when publishing a Post, then use `get_post_meta`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/ to read and compare the date and replace the metas. Packed the code in a function then use in the header.php file.